# Given a matrix $A(x)$ for $x$ real, is $0$ an eigen value of this matrix?

Tags: linear-algebra

Matrix is
A(x) =
$$
    \begin{pmatrix}
    1+x^2 & 7& 11 \\
    2x & 3x & 4 \\
    8x & 17 & 13 \\
     \end{pmatrix} x \in R
$$
I have to show that $0$ is eigenvalue of $A(x)$ for some $x$.
what I can think of is if determinant of matrix $A(x) = 0$ for some $x$ then $0$ is eigen value.
There must be some other way of approaching such question since finding determinate involve a lot of calculation.

Comment: It is not so much calculation for a 3x3 matrix. You should try it out: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rule_of_Sarrus I don't think there is a more simple way.

Comment: We can see that the determinant will be a polynomial of degree at most $3$. If you can show that it is indeed cubic (i.e. the coefficient of $x^3$ is nonzero), then we know it has a real root.

Comment: And indeed the degree is $3$, because there is exactly one permutation $\sigma$ (namely the identity) such that $a_{1,\sigma(1)} a_{2, \sigma(2)} a_{3, \sigma(3)}$ is cubic.

Comment: What is the problem that led to this matrix? If it's arbitrary then I think you have no hope for a fast way.

Comment: @Amr no this is not an arbitrary matrix this is question from csir net exam.

Comment: @Karl yes yes determinant is indeed in cubic form. so it will atleast has a real root(or all three real) . I got it thanks.

Comment: Thank you every one. This was my first question on stack-exchange.

Comment: $0$ is an eigenvalue if & only if the kernel is non-trivial, i.e. the determinant is $0$.